# Is the domain model/JPA entity model supposed to create a well-designed database table structure?

Tags: jpa, database-design

Let's assume the domain model of an application that is supposed to be built from scratch is described as follows:

A Person might live at an address. A Person can own multiple cars.

If I had to design the database first, I would probably come up with the following database design (normalization, cascading, etc. are not supposed to play a major role for my concrete question).

```
Person (id, name)
Address (id, street, zip, city, person_id)
Car (id, manufacturer, yearBuilt, color, person_id)
```

I have mainly followed standard design concepts (e.g. described in this link http://db.grussell.org/section006.html).

As you can see the address table has a foreign key to the person table as the person - address relationship can be considered optional.

The fact that a person can own multiple cars is implemented by putting a foreign key to a person in the car table. I think this is the standard way of modelling 1..m relationships.

If I had to design the domain model first, I would probably come up with the following design:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private Address address;
    private List<Car> cars;

    // Getters and setters
}

public class Address {

    private String street;
    private String zip;
    private String city;

    // Getters and setters
}

public class Car {

    private String color;
    private Date yearBuilt;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

In that domain model, the `Person` class has all necessary relationships. The `Address` and `Car` classes do not need to know anything about their owning `Person`.

I could now turn these classes into JPA entities by adding `@Entity` and providing an `@Id` attribute for every class.

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    private Address address;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Car> cars;

    public Person() { }

    // Getters and setters
}

@Entity
class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private String zip;
    private String city;

    public Address() { }

    // Getters and setters
}

@Entity
class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String color;
    private Date yearBuilt;

    public Car() { }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

If my JPA provider creates the tables according to the provided annotations, the following database structure is created:

```
Person (id, name, address_id)
Address (id, street, zip, city)
Car (id, manufacturer, yearBuilt, color)
Person_Car (person_id, car_id)
```

As you can see, that does not correspond to the database structure I would create if I had to design the database first. I see a few flaws in the database model created by the JPA provider:

1. As the person - address relationship is optional, I would have put the foreign key to a Person into the Address table and not vice versa.
2. As the standard way of modelling a 1..m relationship is to put the foreign key of the owning class into the detail class, I would have never come up with a relation or association table. Why would I want to have that if the relation is not described by additional attributes?
3. To join a Person to a Car, the JPA provider needs to perform an additional join to the relation or association table. Does this measurably decrease the performance?

What I could do now is to provide the JPA entity classes with additional fields and/or annotations to strive for the database structure one might expect.

Is it desirable to strive for a domain model/JPA entity design that is able to create an expected database structure (as if database-first-approach was used)? If so, is it acceptable to have a domain model that is different from a domain model one would create intuitively? What are the advantages in designing a domain model/JPA entity model that will create some sort of "best practice" database structure?

Comment: you question tends to be too broad, as there are so many sub-questions in it...

Answer (score 0):

Update the mapping from Person to Car as below:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private List<Car> cars;
```

the DDL generator of your JPA provider should then create the desired table structure.